# printing a method onto a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, methods

So i have been trying to print a method onto a Jpanel with no success, the method works on the console but i cant get it to print to the Jpanel, I am fairly new to Java, so if you have any advice could you keep it fairly simple :D. I have tried several solutions to similar questions on here to no avail here is the Code.

```
public class fizzbuzz {

private static MouseEvent fizzBuzz() {
    String fizz = "Fizz";
    String buzz = "Buzz";
    String fB = "Fizz buzz";
    int num = 0;

    while(num <= 100) {
        num++;

        if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 != 0) {
            System.out.println (fizz);
            }
        else if (num % 5 == 0 && num % 3 != 0) {
            System.out.println (buzz);
        }
        else if (num % 3 == 0 && num % 5 == 0){
            System.out.println (fB);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void ShowGUI(String[] args) {
    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton okButton = new JButton("Start count");
    okButton.setFont(new Font("Malina Light", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 14));
    final JLabel Jlab = new JLabel();
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Jlab.getToolTipText(fizzBuzz());
        }
    });

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    content.add(Jlab, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Gui test");
    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(250,  250);
    window.setLocation(100, 100);
    window.setVisible(true);;

}

public static void main(String[]args){
    //fizzBuzz();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ShowGUI(args);
                }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: "I am fairly new to Java" - in that case I'd suggest you first stick to the console and grab the basics. Once you have a profound understanding on how Java works you could switch over to GUIs. At the moment you're trying to take 5 steps at a time and that is very likely to end in trouble and confusion.

Comment: By your code you look totally lost. In this situation, if you absolutely need to use Swing, then read the Swing tutorials, don't guess.  You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
Jlab.getToolTipText(fizzBuzz());
```

that is absolute nonsense. This call will invoke your static method, yes. But beyond that it does **nothing** to get text into your JLabel.

The javadoc for [getToolTipText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getToolTipLocation(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) says:

> Returns the tooltip location in this component's coordinate system.

Hint: try `jLabel.setText("some string");` instead.

And then: decide what you want to do: either you want to print to the console (as your `fizzBuzz()` method does) **or** you update UI elements.

Beyond that: read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, and variables/fields go camelCase. By deviating from such standards you make reading your source code much harder.

And the **real** answer is: don't just call some method because you maybe *assume* it makes sense. When you write code, each character, each keyword, each and every *thing* do matter. Don't write something down that you do not understand. Instead - read the corresponding documentation for example. Learning Swing UIs by trial/error will not work - that stuff is simply too complicated to get right. Thus: start reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for example to learn how to work with JLabels.

Comment: "that is absolute nonsense." - exaclty, next to the fact that `Jlab` is a strance name and that `getToolTipText()` doesn't even take parameters ;)

Comment: This is obviously a HW problem, one that he's struggling with.

Comment: @Thomas I mentioned the name - but for the record: there is a method that takes a MouseEvent. It returns the position where the tool tip would appear methinks.

Comment: Ah you're right, my outline didn't show it at first ;)

Comment: "Home work". He was likely told to display his fizz buzz output in a Swing GUI, but is totally lost.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I guess we both read HW as hardware ... ;)

Comment: `don't just call some method because you maybe assume it makes sense. When you write code, each character, each keyword, each and every thing do matter. Don't write something down that you do not understand` Totally agree. Some students just like to throw in some random code and hope that it will work miraculously. I guess OP is too eager to get the thing done.

Comment: @user3437460 Seems that many people can relate to such answers. Although I am a bit surprised that these "likes" do not manifest in upvotes ... but well, it seems to be one of these days ...

Comment: Cheers @GhostCat, the hint was Extremely useful, i solved that portion of the problem i have been having thank  you

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
private static MouseEvent fizzBuzz() {
```

What is the point of the above method signature? Why would you ever return a `MouseEvent`. The method has nothing to do with a mouse.

> So i have been trying to print a method onto a Jpanel with no success

Where? I don't see any logic in your code that attempts to do this. In any case you don't display text on the panel, you display text in a component that you add to the panel.

So start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics.

1. Start with the section on `How to Use Text Areas`. There is demo code you can download that shows you how to append text to a text area.
2. You can then try the section on `How to Write a MouseListener`. Again the demo code shows how to add text to the text area when a MouseEvent is generated.

Using these two examples should help you better structure your code and allow you to append text to a text area instead of use System.out.println(...).